# Dynamic Generator in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, iterator, generator

I need to create a service that can manage a dynamic resource (I'm thinking on a dynamic csv that is growing. In this case I used a list to make more easy to understand), returning the next item from an iterable.

If the list is finished, the output would be False and I need to wait that an element is added.

When the element if finally added, the generator should yield the new added item (this is the part that I can not understand how to do).

```py
a_lst = [1, 2]


class DynamicGenerator:
    """
    Generic Generator that return item by item from a_lst and
    can append a new item when needed.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        global a_lst

    def gen_lst(self):
        for item in a_lst:
            yield item

    def grow_lst(self, new_item):
        a_lst.append(new_item)

class AvailableNextIterator:
    """
    Return next item from iterable if it's available,
    else return False.
    """
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterator = iterable

    def __next__(self):
        return next(self.iterator, False)


dg = DynamicGenerator()
gl = dg.gen_lst()

it = AvailableNextIterator(gl)

print(it.__next__())
print(it.__next__())
print(it.__next__())

dg.grow_lst(3)

print(it.__next__())
```

This is the code output:

```
1
2
False
False
```

This is the output that I need:

```
1
2
False
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simply, you exhausted the iteration *before* you added the last item; you already tripped the end-of-data exception for `gen_list`.  You've dropped out of the loop, and there's no provision to re-enter.  You can see this with a little simple tracing in that method:

```
def gen_lst(self):
    for item in a_lst:
        yield item
    print("gen_lst is out of data")
    yield "over the cliff's edge ..."
```

Now, the output is

```
1
2
gen_lst is out of data
over the cliff's edge ...
False
```

You seem to want a FIFO queue; I suggest that you use the available data structure in the readily-available packages, rather than trying to roll your own.

However, if this is a homework exercise:

1. Mark your question as such, as required by SO posting standards;
2. Research existing implementations.

Maintain the queue as an attribute of the instance, not an external variable.  Your "generator" should check the queue directly, rather than depending on `for` to manage the iteration.